# Unpacking a list of lists in a for loop

Tags: python, list

Let's say I create a list in the following way:

```
a = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

If I execute the following for loop:

```
for b in a:
    print(b)
```

I get

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
```

which makes sense to me because I am looking for elements of `a` which, in that case, are sub-lists. However, if I execute:

```
for b, c in a:
    print(b, c)
```

I get

```
0 1
2 3
```

I would have expected to get

```
[0, 1] [2, 3]
```

Is there an obvious reason why Python is unpacking the list this way? I mean, why Python would suddenly give me elements of sub-elements of my list when I am requesting objects in the list?

Comment: Are you expecting `for b in a:` and `for b, c  in a:` do the same thing?

Comment: It useful to think of `for b, c in a` as `for x in a: <newline> b, c = x #Unpack 'x'`

Comment: You seem to think that `for b, c in a` is equivalent to `b = a[0], c = a[1]`. If `a` would contain a third pair , what is your expectation then?

Comment: @UltraInstinct Thank you very much, that helps.

Comment: @guidot You could argue exactly the same about the number of elements of the sub-lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specified:

```
for b, c in a:
    print(b, c)
```

You could read that as: `for each element in a, unpack into the tuple "b, c"`

Comment: I am accepting your answer, which is similar to @UltraInstinct comment, because it is simple and it covers exactly what I was missing and thereby asking for.

Answer (score 3):

You're unpacking to the integers here:

```
>>> for b, c in a:
...     print(b, c)
...     print(type(b), type(c))
... 
0 1
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
2 3
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Put another way, compare the following two:

```
>>> b, c = a; print(b, c)
[0, 1] [2, 3]
>>> b, c = a[0]; print(b,c)
0 1
```

Comment: Formulated differently: the `for` loop gets rid of the first nesting level. By using the compound assignment (whether in `for a, b = ` or in `b, c = a`) one gets rid of the second level. If this is not desired, use no compound unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to understand the [Assignment Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) being used here.  Relevant part here:

> - If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma,
>     optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.
> - Else: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as
>     there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from
>     left to right, to the corresponding targets.

The `for` loop essentially boils down to this:

```
for (object) in (iterable):
```

Now let's see what objects are in your iterable:

```
[0, 1]  # object1: list
[2, 3]  # object2: list
```

But when you use the Assignment Statement, the "Else" clause applies.

```
for (obj1, obj2 of object) in (iterable):
```

Which treats the object as an inner iterable, and unpack each to the inner objects, i.e. the `int`s within:

```
0 1     # obj1 of object1: int, obj2 of object1: int
2 3     # obj1 of object2: int, obj2 of object2: int
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is **unpacking assignment**, which assigns the elements of an iterable to multiple variables. To get your expected behavior, do the following:

```
b, c = a
print(b, c)
```

`for b, c in a:` iterates through `a` the same way as `for b in a:`, but since each element is a 2-element iterable, its own elements get unpacked to `b` and `c`. See what happens when you do this:

```
a = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4]]
for b, c in a:
    print(b, c)
```

You would get an error, because `a[1]` has more elements than there are variables to assign to.